# swagger api model is displaying wrapper classes

Tags: java, rest, swagger, api-doc

we are using swagger for documentation.
We have mentioned @ApiModel on Pojo, problem here is if you have any wrapper classes like Integer, BigDecimal etc it is documenting those classes as well.

Here is the Pojo,

```
@XmlRootElement

@ApiModel
public class AccountSeriesUpdateRequest implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<String> acclist;

private BigDecimal trans;

public List<String> getAcclist() {
    return acclist;
}

public void setAcclist(List<String> acclist) {
    this.acclist = acclist;
}

public BigDecimal getTrans() {
    return trans;
}

public void setTrans(BigDecimal trans) {
    this.trans = trans;
}`
```

And here is the swagger documentation for above model,

```
AccountSeriesUpdateRequest {
trans(BigDecimal, optional): description,

accountSeriesRecord (AccountSeriesPersistentRecord, optional): Account Series Persistent Record,

acclist (array[string], optional)
}

BigDecimal {
scale (integer, optional),
precision (integer, optional)
}
```

Please suggest me a way to get rid of from unwanted object in swagger documentation.

Comment: Which swagger library do you use and which version of it?

Comment: i am using below dependencies, <dependency> 
         <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId> 
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations_2.10</artifactId> 
        <version>1.3.0</version> 
        </dependency> 
        <dependency> 
         <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId> 
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId> 
       <version>1.3.0</version> 
       </dependency> 
    
       <dependency> 
          <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId> 
          <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId> 
          <version>0.9.3</version> 
    </dependency>

Comment: Check out https://github.com/springfox/springfox instead.